# Can't access Intellij auto created RestFul web service server

Tags: java, rest, intellij-idea, restful-architecture

After creating `RestFul Web service` (let's say `helloworld`) using `Intellij Idea`, When I run the server, it runs correctly(`it says Server is running`). But when I try to access it using my web browser, it says **"the web page you are requested is not available"**.

What is wrong with my web service.?
I just created a basic project.

output -

com.sun.jersey.api.core.ScanningResourceConfig logClasses
INFO: Root resource classes found:
  class example.HelloWorld
Dec 26, 2013 3:16:09 PM com.sun.jersey.api.core.ScanningResourceConfig init
INFO: No provider classes found.
Dec 26, 2013 3:16:09 PM com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl _initiate
INFO: Initiating Jersey application, version 'Jersey: 1.3 06/17/2010 05:04 PM'
Server running
Visit: http ://localhost:9998/helloworld
Hit return to stop...

Comment: What is your Intellij version? Are there any exceptions in your programme?

Comment: version 10.0.1
I added the error message to the original question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your helloworld class,there may be a line like following

```
HttpServer server = HttpServerFactory.create("http://localhost:9998/");
```

change the port number to 8080 and try to run again